# How to check if a time falls within a specific range on a week day using vb

Tags: vb.net, time, range

Please am a newbie in VB,and I will like to know how to check if the output time from another script falls between 2 am and 3 am on a weekday and display 1 if true or 0 if false using VB.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `IsTimeInRange()` will return `True` if current time is in the desired range else `False`.

```
Function IsTimeInRange() As Boolean
    Return Now.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday AndAlso
           Now.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Friday AndAlso
           Now.Hour = 2 'Includes everything between "02:00:00.000 AM" and "02:59:59.999 AM"
End Function
```

Comment: Please how can it display 1 for true or 0 for false instead of boolean?

Comment: @qafro This is really basics and straightforward. Just use a simple `If`-clause. There are enough examples and tutorials. Did you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hey, I get  Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement , Any idea of resolve?

Comment: @qafro Did you look at the links i posted in my previous comment? Please don't ask new questions in comments. If your original question is answered mark one as accepted and create a new question with the specific problem you can't solve. No one can help you with just the above error message without seeing the script.

Comment: @qafro _"Microsoft **VBScript**"_?? Is this VBScript? Because that is not the same as VB.NET, and (in the future) you should tag your question accordingly.